# VBA: Create Function Programmatically From VSTO Add-In?

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, ms-office, porting

Is it possible to create VBA function programmatically from a VSTO add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link explains the process for doing what you want via VBA:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

I don't have any experience with VSTO, but the process might map over.

Edit: example here... http://mrvsto.com/2010/04/use-vsto-to-add-vba-code/